# Stop div falling to next line

Tags: html, css, navbar

I wish to add a search field to my navbar by having all my links aligned to the left, and having a search form aligned to the right, with a flex box in between like so:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a...
    <a...
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <div class="search">
        <form>
            <input type="text" style="border:none;" placeholder="Search">
            <input type="image" src="/images/search.png">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS I currently use is:

```
.nav{margin:0 auto;padding:10px 0;max-width:1280px;min-width:800px;width:84%;background:#000 url('../images/navBG.png') repeat-x;}
.nav a{padding:10px;}
.flex{-moz-box-flex:1.0;-webkit-box-flex:1.0;-ms-flex:1.0;box-flex:1.0;}
.search{display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;}
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. Without the search and flex divs (ie, just the navbar links), everything is fine, but adding the search div sends the div to the next line. Trying to bring it back to the same line using text-wrap:none does nothing.

Comment: Did you try to float divs?

Comment: as `div.flex` is a block element, every element after it will display on new line. Add `display: inline-block` to `.flex` element or try to float elements.

Comment: @tilda: I make it a point to never float anything, as it generally causes more issues relating to layout and varying zoom/screen size/resolutions/browser widths.

Comment: @andreivictor: Yes, that worked. However, the flex CSS isn't working. I guess this is now unrelated to this question, but right now, the search div is next to the links, rather than the expected behaviour of the search div being pushed as far to the right as possible by the flex. Perhaps I'm still just unfamiliar with the box-flex.

Comment: I've never used `box-flex`. Maybe [this link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but I would use a table.

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%><tr>
<td width=84% ><div class="nav">  
               <a...
               <a...
               </div></td>
<td><div class="flex">
    </div></td>
<td><div class="search">
    </div></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Nah, I've always been taught to never use tables for anything other than actually displaying information that you would use a table for. I know that some people also recommend using the display property in CSS to use the table attributes, but again, that's something I want to avoid unless I have no choice. Thanks, though.